# CSS - How to make a tag surrounded li

Tags: css

i try to make a list Horizontal like

[image]

I try to make when hover each item (text and dot) then cursor is the same when hover `<a>` tag like

[image]

But it's true for hover `text` not for both `dot` and `text`.

Frist problem: i can't make width is auto include both `dot` and `text`.

Second: I think `a` tag must be surrounded `li` to do: hover both (dot and text).

How to make that work. Thanks

Here is my code **http://jsfiddle.net/Q6CZ2/**

```
<div id="wrap">
      <ul id="navbar">
         <li><a href="#">Exhibits and Events</a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: please share your html and css also

Comment: please edit your question, its very hard to understand.

Comment: @ArunPJohny and someone plz see my edit

Comment: please add the css as well.

Answer (score 1):

try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6CZ2/1/)

it wraps the "li" tags in the "a" tags like so:

```
<a href="#"><li>Exhibits and Events
     </li></a>
```

that may be what you want.

as for you second problem try deleting:

```
* {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

and:

```
#wrap {
margin: 50px;
width:600px;
height:40px;
}
```

also [try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6CZ2/10/)

Comment: thank u, what is about first problem? i can't make with is auto fit (text and dot)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, you want to use:

```
li{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

although i dont know why you want that cursor, because the dot still wont act as a link.

Comment: but my second problem is: when hover both (dot and text) is the same hover `<a>` tag (text)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change the hovered cursor if `li` to pointer to change the cursor of the bulletin mark
2. since you have the rule `#wrap a` it is overriding the color applied by rule `#wrap li:hover`

Try

```
#wrap li:hover, #wrap li:hover a{
    color: #CCC;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wD47D/)

Comment: but my second problem is: when hover both (dot and text) is the same hover <a> tag (text) that is (has link )?

Comment: @trungkien there were two problems right... 1. the cursor, 2. the text color both are fixed now... is there anything else

Comment: no 1. width is auto fit both (dot and text), 2. hover (text and dot) is the same that mean has (pointer and link to click)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your `<a>` tag inside of the `<li>` tag with this:

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#wrap li {
    float:left;
}
#wrap {
    /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
    margin: 50px;
    width:600px;
    height:40px;
}
#wrap li {
    width:150px;
    color:green;
}
#wrap a {
    margin-left:-20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    color:green;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
#wrap li:hover,
#wrap li:hover a {
    color: #CCC;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6CZ2/9/

Comment: i think u don't understand my question: 1. width is auto fit both (dot and text), 2. hover (text and dot) is the same that mean has (pointer and link to click) thanks